# Adapter pattern : Why would we need to subclass the Adaptee?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, polymorphism

For an Object Adapter design, GoF states :

> makes it harder to override Adaptee behavior. It will require subclassing Adaptee and making Adapter refer to the subclass rather than the Adaptee itself

My question is that why is this subclassing required when we are creating the clases as follows :

```
class Target {
    public :
    virtual void op() = 0 ;
} ;

class Adaptee {
    public :
    void adapteeOp() {cout<<"adaptee op\n" ;}
} ;

class Adapter : public Target {
    Adaptee *adaptee ;
    public :
    Adapter(Adaptee *a) : adaptee(a) {}
    void op() {
        // added behavior
        cout<<"added behavior\n" ;
        adaptee->adapteeOp() ;
        // more added behavior
        cout<<"more added behavior\n" ;
    }
} ;

main() { //client
    Adapter adapter(new Adaptee) ;
    adapter.op() ;
}
```

I have not been able to appreciate the requirement for subclassing as mentioned by GoF when I am able to override the behavior here also.

Please explain what is the point that I am missing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have not been able to appreciate the requirement for subclassing as mentioned by GoF when I am able to override the behavior here also.

I see your confusion. Your example is too simple as it only contains `cout` statements. I wouldn't qualify adding `cout` statements before and after a call to one of `Adaptee`s methods as adding any significant behavior. You need to consider more complex scenarios.

Imagine that you want to add `newFunctionality` to the `Adaptee` that uses the protected data from `Adaptee`. You can't modify the `Adaptee` so the only option you have is to subclass it.

```
class NewAdaptee : public Adaptee {
    public :
    void adapteeOp() {
        cout<<"adaptee op\n" ; //step 3
    }

    void newFunctionality() { //use protected members from Adaptee }
} ;
```

The above code demonstrates a more complex use case of adding functionality to the `Adaptee` where subclassing is the only way to achieve this. So you now want to start using this new `Adaptee` in your `Adapter`. If you go with the *object adapter* option, you will need to start using a `NewAdaptee` reference in the `Adaptor`

```
class Adapter : public Target {
    NewAdaptee *adaptee ;
    //more code follows
}
```

This has the immediate issue that your `Adapter` can no longer be passed any direct subclasses of `Adaptee`. This is what they mean when they say *It will require subclassing Adaptee and making Adapter refer to the subclass rather than the Adaptee itself*. This would take away the advantage of the *object adapter* approach which was to allow a single adapter to work with all the subclasses of the `Adaptee`.

**Note :** In the *class adapter* approach, `NewAdaptee` would actually be your adapter and would also inherit `Target`.